# Unable to insert data in array field in snowflake table using javascript

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
let gpt3Embedding= async (content) => {
    try {
        const response =  openai.embeddings.create({
            model: "text-embedding-ada-002",
            input: content,
            encoding_format: 'float',
        });
        const vector = response.data[0]['embedding']; 
        return vector;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}



router.post('/saveChat', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.session.isAuthenticated) {
            let sql_text = "";
            const chats = req.body;
            var result = null;
            let empty_arr=[];
            console.log(chats)
            let create_by = req.session.account.localAccountId
            if (Object.keys(chats.session).length > 0) {
                // check if Session exists if not create a new one

                const conn = await mainConnection();
                result = await conn.execute(`select count(session_id) as cnt from CHAT_SESSION_PWT where session_id='${chats.session.session_id}' and created_by='${create_by}'`);

                console.log(result)
                console.log(`select count(session_id) from CHAT_SESSION_PWT where session_id='${chats.session.session_id}' and created_by='${create_by}'`);

                if (result[0].CNT == 0) {
                    sql_text = `insert into CHAT_SESSION_PWT (session_id,session_name,create_on,created_by)
                    VALUES ('${chats.session.session_id}','${chats.session.session_name}',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,'${create_by}')`
                    result = await conn.execute(sql_text);
                }
                
                if (chats.chat.length > 0) {                    
                    sql_text = `INSERT INTO user_chat_pwt (
                        chat_id,
                        chat_question_id,
                        session_id,
                        chat_role,
                        content,
                        content_raw,
                        documents,
                        query_embedding,                        
                        chat_like,
                        dislike,
                        pin,
                        response_table,
                        insights,
                        graph,                      
                        steps,
                        knowledge_base,
                        usage,
                        sequence_no,
                        query_category,
                        question,
                        resTime
                    ) VALUES `;

                    for (let i in chats.chat) {
                         let vec = [];
                        await gpt3Embedding(chats.chat[i].content).then(vector => vec=vector);
                        sql_text += `(
                        '${chats.chat[i].chat_id}',
                        '${chats.chat[i].chat_question_id}',
                        '${chats.session.session_id}',
                        '${chats.chat[i].chat_role}',
                        '${chats.chat[i].content}',
                        '${JSON.stringify(chats.chat[i].content_raw).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',
                        '${JSON.stringify(chats.chat[i].documents).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',
                        '${JSON.stringify([vec])}',
                        ${chats.chat[i].chat_like},
                        ${chats.chat[i].dislike},
                        ${chats.chat[i].pin},
                        '${JSON.stringify(chats.chat[i].response_table).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',
                        '${chats.chat[i].insights}',
                        '${JSON.stringify(chats.chat[i].graph).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',                      
                        '${(chats.chat[i].steps).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',
                        '${(chats.chat[i].knowledge_base).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',
                        '${JSON.stringify(chats.chat[i].usage).replace(/\'/g, "\"")}',
                        ${chats.chat[i].sequence_no},
                        '${chats.chat[i].query_category}',
                        '${chats.chat[i].question}',
                        ${chats.chat[i].resTime}
                        ),`
                    }

                    sql_text = sql_text.substring(0, sql_text.length - 1)
                    console.log("\x1b[31m", sql_text);
                    result = await conn.execute(sql_text);
                }


                closeConnection(conn);

                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: true,
                    data: result,
                });

            }
            else {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status: false,
                    error: "No chats availabe to save",
                });
            }
        } else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                status: false,
                error: 'unauthorised',
            });
        }

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            error: err,
        });
    }

});
```

I have been trying to insert an array in vector column (Array type ) in snowflake database.

The array has been generated using await

```
gpt3Embedding(chats.chat[i].content).then(vector => vec=vector);
The insert is at '${JSON.stringify(vec)}',
```

The save is failing with 500 error.

The error details at console is

```
{status: false, error: {}}
error : {}
status :  false
```

The only successful way of adding data was using the hardcoding -

```
'${JSON.stringify([0.013054623,0.020803465,-0.01879506,-0.02726333,-0.0029545266,0.021477928,0.006006476,-0.012222785,-0.013736581])}',
```

Expecting the data to be inserted in the snowflake table .

Comment: The output from gtp3embedding is expected to be like this  [
     0.015425107,   0.009208673,  -0.019159608,  -0.016762724,  -0.018494666,
     0.030370839, -0.0016952155, -0.0077202856,  -0.020953404,  0.0004820346,
  -0.00061275176,   -0.03001517,  0.0073955464, -0.0043569165, -0.0006833052,
     0.004097898,   0.005497369,  -0.012015346,   0.009834955,  -0.017721476,
      ... 1436 more items
]